# Custom Logging Best Practices in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

What are best practices for managing custom logging in Ruby? Should I be monkeypatching logger to do what I want? Or extending from it? Or delegating? What's the rubyish way? I'm sick of custom hacks for this; I'd like something cleaner, and ideally more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my experience, log4r is no more popular (and I don't know why these days I can't access log4r's homepage). Instead [logging](https://rubygems.org/gems/logging) is far more better.

FYR

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/logging

Answer (score 7):

Bates has a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/56-the-logger) on customizing logger.

And here is a blog post on custom [logging in Rails](http://ianma.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/custom-logging-in-ruby-on-rails/).

Here are some tips on [logging in Rails](https://web.archive.org/web/20100527042613/http://maintainable.com:80/articles/rails_logging_tips).

Answer (score 1):

There's a Ruby implementation of Slf4j, the popular Java logging framework, imaginatively called [Slf4r](https://github.com/mkristian/slf4r). This separates the actual logging method from the code, and provides a standard interface for logging different message levels.