# Singleton logger usage in ruby

Tags: ruby, logging

I have the code like below:

```
require 'logger'
require 'singleton'

class Logger
    include Singleton
    @@old_initialize = Logger.instance_method :initialize

    def initialize
        @@old_initialize.bind(self).call(STDERR)
    end  
end 

class MyClass
    def initialize
        @logger = Logger.new("output.log")
    end
end
```

I am getting following error while running MyClass.

> in `initialize': private method`new' called for Logger:Class
>   (NoMethodError)

I'm using Ruby Version:

> ruby 1.8.6 (2009-08-04 patchlevel 383) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: What is your question? (TM)

Comment: Question is, "Why am I receiving NoMethodError"? Can you help in resolving?

Comment: Don't call `new`? Use `:send` instead, but make sure that you *actually* want to do that, and doing so doesn't break everything else? Don't make it a singleton, where calling `new` doesn't make any sense, because There Can Be Only One?

Answer (score 3):

Let us look at the documentation of [Module: Singleton](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html). Including the module ensures, that only one instance of your class can be created by making the `initialize` method private. Hence, you receive `NoMethodError - new is private` error. Further it says:

> > The instance is created at upon the first call of `Klass.instance()`.

So instead of `.new` you make a call to `.instance`

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
     @logger = Logger.instance()
  end
end
```

Now you can call `MyClass.new` and it will return your logger object. This way, however, you cannot pass an additional parameter. So the question here really is, why does it need to be a Singleton in the first place?

Comment: All I need is to create/utilize logger feature in my code base. We never tried this earlier. My whole application runs on batch mode and has interactions with 10-15 classes. I wanted to use logger and I somewhere came across the code given above, creating singleton logger. I am not sure I need singleton or not. I need to create logging facility in all the classes of my application. Any good example demonstrating an example for my need would be more helpful. NOTE: I also require to log the class name, method and line number during logging. How to achieve this?

Comment: @user2562153 Then just use the vanilla logger, do not modify it http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_logging.html

Comment: I looked at the logger. I seems simple. But, I need to do custom logging with my own levels, message indicating the module::module::class, method and line number from where the particular logging happened. Can I achieve this with logger?

Comment: @user2562153 Well, not out of the box. If you want the freedom described there are several approaches/libraries. I would recommend looking into the answers of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528481/custom-logging-best-practices-in-ruby